# Standard way to statically sign a web page

Tags: http, cryptography, http-headers, digital-signature

Suppose I have a valid (i.e. signed by one of the commonly trusted authorities) cryptographic certificate on my server. I could obviously use it to establish https sessions and deliver the contents with confidentiality (only the endpoints can read them), authentication (both endpoints know who they're talking to) and reliability (the message can't be tampered).

Now suppose that I actually don't care about the first two but, instead, I just the need the last one. For example, let's say I have a static resource that I would like to sign (a-la PGP) so that I can give it to other untrusted hosts: if my certificate is public and the resource has been signed with it, any client should be able to verify that the resource has not been tampered (e.g. by the untrusted host).

The question now is: is there a standard way to statically sign a web page? (I obviously mean something builtin in all browsers) I'm aware of someone ([Unhosted](http://www.unhosted.org/manifesto.html)) who's trying to accomplish something like this by implementing much of the logic via Javascript but still I'm wondering if a more standard way exists.

Comment: A tiny bit of history. People know about https but most have never heard of an earlier competitor called shttp. It never caught on while https took off, but shttp was message based and built around SMIME standards.

Comment: One idea: You could offer the `NONE` cipher algorithm in your SSL server (but together with a MAC algorithm to ensure authenticity). But I suppose most browsers won't accept it (and rightly so, as most users really want confidentiality with HTTPS).

Comment: I'm fairly sure no such thing exists, but you could almost certainly write a browser extension that implements it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such standard implementation **builtin** in a browser.

Even in the mail area where such behavior is "standard" for long time (S/MIME), we find issues every other day with different clients, relays and servers.

For a download you may revert to sending a PKCS#7 container and associate a tool that unpacks and verifies. At least plugins and helper applications are availabel everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not aware of any standard implementation like that within a browser.  But, to back up a bit... some things to consider:

1. For executable content (like downloaded EXE files, ActiveX controls, Windows Installer, etc.), a common / standard solution is Microsoft Authenticode.  See http://www.tech-pro.net/code-signing-for-developers.html.  Similar solutions for Java, Adobe, etc.  The CA you buy the cert from will verify your identity.  When you sign an EXE file with a cert from a trusted CA, Internet Explorer will display the signer information / less scary warning message.  Same goes for UAC elevation prompts in Windows Vista/7.  You're probably familiar with this?
2. But for the static content situation, the standard solution is SSL.  May I ask why SSL isn't an acceptable solution in your application?

   The problem I see is that there's no way for the user to verify the identity of the web page from the web browser, other than clicking the SSL "lock" icon in the browser to view the certificate.  The new SSL EV certificates should verify that you control the domain in question, and that you are who you say you are (i.e. not be able to get a "PayPal" certificate for www.paypal.com.hacker.cz).

It sounds from your question that you're looking for an "Authenticode for web pages" sort of thing:  a certificate with a subject not tied to a domain name and where the web page could go anywhere.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any such thing for standard HTML files.  I believe you can sign things like Adobe AIR applications, which can be based on HTML / Javascript / etc., although I'm not familiar with that platform.  It does place the web page outside of the user's normal web browser, of course.

Comment: Take, for example, Wikipedia. If it could sign a static version of each article that can be served to non-authenticated users, a distributed CDN run by volunteers on their untrusted hosts could be feasible. Without the static signing, this is not possible. But with it, a client requesting a static version from an untrusted host could still be sure that the resource has not been tampered by the CDN (or other proxies).

The reason for all this would obviously be reducing operating costs and possibly improving QoS.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying.  No web browser I'm aware of has this kind of functionality - the only real security guarantee provided by SSL.  Presumably you need some kind of secure embedded "web browser within a web browser" that checks the signatures on content from other hosts, initially hosted on your trusted server via SSL.  Presumably you can have JavaScript on your main page (served via SSL) download other static content (e.g. images), check the signature, and refuse to display it if it fails.  As long as this JavaScript originates from your server via SSL, it would be somewhat secure.

Comment: Actually here's a simpler way.  Forget the digital signatures and just use SHA-1 or SHA-2 hashes.  Your main page (served via SSL) would have JavaScript that pulls in the static content like so:  (1) download the static content, (2) calculate hash, (3) make sure the hash matches the expected hash for that content.  If a match, display content; else, do not display content.  The problem with just using signatures is that attacker could still switch the content around.  For example, swap images by renaming them.  Might be a big deal if switching things like a Delete button and a Cancel button!

Comment: @James Where would you get the authoritative hashes from? And signatures encode the hash of the content they're signing - so an attacker can't modify the content without invalidating the signature - that's the whole point.

Comment: @Nick:  He'd have to download them from his server via SSL.  The OP says he doesn't care about authentication, but he actually needs that for the initial step of his scheme for downloading trusted code to the client.  I don't see a way around that.  He could use that initial trusted connection over SSL to transfer hashes of the distributed content.  Or, use it to send his public key that he signed the content with.  (But, he needs to include the relative path as part of the data he is signing, otherwise he exposes himself to the attack I mention at the end of my last comment!)

Comment: @James Easy: He can use the existing PKI scheme of SSL certificates, and the publisher can sign the doc with that, like he was proposing. The browser can authenticate the signature using the certificate chain in the same fashion as it would for an SSL connection.

Comment: @Nick: Right, but how to do that if delivering content over an unencrypted HTTP connection like the OP was wanting?  I'm not aware of any built-in browser functionality that can do this?

Comment: @James I think we've already established that there's no built-in browser feature that does this. My point is that you don't need to reinvent the wheel - the cryptosystems and PKI infrastructure already exist.